# AUGraph and streaming audio (http and ets)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have player based on AUGraph (i need equalizer). Player can play local audio files. Now i want to add support stream audio. What i can use for it ? Anyone standart class like AVAssetReader (AVAssertReader can't play stream :( ), or maybe anyone know open lib for it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As steaming is now supported natively in AVPlayer, there aren't too libs which are actively supported. One which has been around for some time (i've used it myself in the past) is Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer, https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer, or Thong Nguyen StreamingKit, https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

An alternative approach you might want to consider is an implementation similar to the one demonstrated in Apple's AudioTapProcessor. Essentially inserting an **MTAudioProcessingTap** into AVPlayer's pipeline to introduces a **kAudioUnitSubType_BandPassFilter** AudioUnit. A similar approach could be used to introduce an **kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ** AudioUnit.

Comment: AVPlayer can't use equalizer, Streaming kit is good, but don't correct stack with my visualizer, audio streamer i will see. Thanks.

Comment: As i mentioned, you could use a AudioProcessingTap with AVPlayer for your Equalizer.