# Had Apple AudioUnit what implemented Automatic Gain Reduction (AGR)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I have AVPlayer with AudioProcessorTap for equalizer (how this [AUGraph and streaming audio (http and ets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787606/augraph-and-streaming-audio-http-and-ets/23788841?noredirect=1#comment36624250_23788841)) and now i want to add Automatic Gain Reduction for this player. Anyone know AudioUnit or filter for this? I try to find it in documentation, but it seems like apple don't make AGR code. I don't want make bicycle. Thanks.